# appmetrics(https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics/issues) request and http event not working

Tags: node.js

Hi Please see below sample code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var appmetrics = require('appmetrics');
var monitor = appmetrics.monitor();
appmetrics.enable('http');
appmetrics.enable('request');
monitor.on('request', function (request) {
        console.log('request', request);
});
monitor.on('http', function (http) {
        console.log('http', http);
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

'

Whenever I fire localhost:3000 from browser. I get 'Hello World!' reply but logs doesn't show any request or http event. Can somebody help me to point out issue.
I am using latest appmetrics version.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I alos tried express event(in v2.0.1). It is also not working for same code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting line 4 (the appmetrics require line) at the top of the code? If it works, please close the issue you raised https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics/issues/452